# Cosa significa "mondo scontornato" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Una volta sola si sciacquò la faccia a lungo per cacciar via lo stordimento del vino, l’impressione di **mondo scontornato**. Non ci riuscì, anzi le crebbe il sentimento che i suoi stessi gesti mancassero di coordinazione.

Ho cercato il significato di "scontornare" e, nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scontornare/), ho trovato

> Nella tecnica tipografica, eliminare da una fotografia, con opportune modalità, ciò che non interessa dell’immagine per riprodurre solo il particolare di cui si vuole dare l’illustrazione: *s. una moneta, una testa, il capitello di una colonna*; *statua, fontana scontornata*.

Le definizioni di altri dizionari sono simili. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il senso di "mondo scontornato" nel brano sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 1):

Quando si beve troppo, in italiano si dice che "si vede doppio", vale a dire che i contorni degli oggetti e delle persone sembrano "doppi", non precisi, sfocati; un po' la sensazione che si ha quando si sta per svenire. La persona di cui si parla nella citazione vuole, con l'acqua (fredda, immagino), superare questa sensazione, ma non riesce.